# How to parse the json array in golang?

Tags: json, go, struct

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type PublicKey struct {
    name string
    price string
}

type KeysResponse struct {
    Collection []PublicKey
}

func main() {
    s := `[{"name":"Galaxy Nexus", "price":"3460.00"},{"name":"Galaxy Nexus", "price":"3460.00"}]`

    keys := make([]PublicKey,0)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &keys)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", keys)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", keys)
    }
}
```

OutPut: `[{name: price:}]`

I have api call returned result it is like array of object (json array) complex format. I need to parse that result by golang how can I achieve? Following data is my result it is get from api call.

```
[{"id":694476444991229955,"id_str":"694476444991229955","text":"Got it","sender":{"id":1690262984,"id_str":"1690262984","name":"Ashok Kumar T","screen_name":"Ashok_kumar_T","location":"Trivandrum","description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":68,"friends_count":32,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Thu Aug 22 06:52:53 +0000 2013","favourites_count":5,"utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"Chennai","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":124,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"131516","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1690262984\/1429709252","profile_link_color":"009999","profile_sidebar_border_color":"EEEEEE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":true,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"sender_id":1690262984,"sender_id_str":"1690262984","sender_screen_name":"Ashok_kumar_T","recipient":{"id":4848598394,"id_str":"4848598394","name":"Prabhu","screen_name":"prabhu_cfml","location":"","description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":1,"friends_count":1,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Tue Feb 02 09:25:17 +0000 2016","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":0,"lang":"en-gb","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":null,"profile_background_image_url_https":null,"profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_link_color":"2B7BB9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":true,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"recipient_id":4848598394,"recipient_id_str":"4848598394","recipient_screen_name":"prabhu_cfml","created_at":"Tue Feb 02 11:04:21 +0000 2016","entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[]}},{"id":694476425793916931,"id_str":"694476425793916931","text":"Hi","sender":{"id":1690262984,"id_str":"1690262984","name":"Ashok Kumar T","screen_name":"Ashok_kumar_T","location":"Trivandrum","description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":68,"friends_count":32,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Thu Aug 22 06:52:53 +0000 2013","favourites_count":5,"utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"Chennai","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":124,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"131516","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000337984382\/5eded5a0c6fda4a85511aff15e5befd9_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1690262984\/1429709252","profile_link_color":"009999","profile_sidebar_border_color":"EEEEEE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":true,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"sender_id":1690262984,"sender_id_str":"1690262984","sender_screen_name":"Ashok_kumar_T","recipient":{"id":4848598394,"id_str":"4848598394","name":"Prabhu","screen_name":"prabhu_cfml","location":"","description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":1,"friends_count":1,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Tue Feb 02 09:25:17 +0000 2016","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":0,"lang":"en-gb","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":null,"profile_background_image_url_https":null,"profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_link_color":"2B7BB9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":true,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false},"recipient_id":4848598394,"recipient_id_str":"4848598394","recipient_screen_name":"prabhu_cfml","created_at":"Tue Feb 02 11:04:17 +0000 2016","entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[]}}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed one point only: you need to export the fields of your struct:

```
type PublicKey struct {
    Name  string
    Price string
}
```

And it will work (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/-ArSqyIALx)):

```
[{Name:Galaxy Nexus Price:3460.00} {Name:Galaxy Nexus Price:3460.00}]
```

Note that the JSON text contains the field names with lowercased text, but the `json` package is "clever" enough to match them. If they would be completely different, you could use struct tags to tell the `json` package how they are found (or how they should be marshaled) in the JSON text, e.g.:

```
type PublicKey struct {
    Name  string `json:"some_name"`
    Price string `json:"JsonPrice"`
}
```

To parse your other JSON text, create a Go struct that models the JSON data. I suggest to format the JSON to see the real structure, e.g. you can use this [online JSON formatter/validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Then you can unmarshal into a slice of this struct.

Or simply unmarshal into a slice of maps, e.g. `[]map[string]interface{}`, but then you need to index the map to get the different values, and you also need to use type assertion to get "typed" values.

Comment: Thank. But how can i parse the following data   [{
 "id": 694476444991229955,
 "id_str": "694476444991229955",
 "text": "Got it",
 "sender": {
  "id": 1690262984,
  "id_str": "1690262984",
  "name": "Ashok Kumar T",
  "screen_name": "Ashok_kumar_T",
  "location": "Trivandrum",
  "description": "",
  "url": null,
  "entities": {
   "description": {
    "urls": []
   }
  },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 68,
  "friends_count": 32,
  
 }]

Comment: I am a new guy for golang. Can you give the golangplay url for one complex json parse example please?

Comment: @cfprabhu Your example, but change the type of `keys`, e.g. `keys := []map[string]interface{}{}`.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/4U4oDvOBRA   But i get invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string

Comment: @cfprabhu Because the json you try to unmarshal is invalid, remove the last comma in this line: `"url": null,`