# Error with JSON parsing in Golang

Tags: json, parsing, go

I develop this code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Client struct{
    host string
    key string
    secrete string
    username string
    password string
}

type Config struct{
    Client []Client
}

func main(){
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("conf2.json")
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Print("Error:",err)
    }
    var conf Config
    err=json.Unmarshal(content, &conf)
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Print("Error:",err)
    }
    json.Unmarshal(content, &conf)
    fmt.Println(conf.Client[0].host)
}
```

to parse and print the first host detail from my json, that looks like this:

> {
>         "Client" :
>         [
>             {"host":"192.168.1.2"},
>             {"key":"abcdf"},
>             {"secrete":"9F6w"},
>             {"username":"user"},
>             {"password":"password"}
>         ]
>       }

But I got an empty string. Could someone know the reason?

Comment: Your JSON is a bit weird - any reason why you have each property in a separate object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse the json array in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202961/how-to-parse-the-json-array-in-golang)

Comment: Modify your code to get the error from `json.Unmarshal()` and print it so you can see what went wrong. You have a number of problems though, firstly, none of the properties on `Client` are exported meaning they can't be assigned to.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen no reason... I'm very new to the Go language and the parsing in general. Please, could you show me the right sintax? Thank you.

Comment: @DarkSkull: I think something like `{"Client": [ {"host": "192.168.1.2", "key": "foo", "secret": "bar" }, { "host": "192..." } ] }` would make more sense in most cases. Note how all the properties are inside one set of `{}` making them part of the same object.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Ok thanks! But now, how can I access every single information?

Comment: @DarkSkull: I don't use go myself so you'll have to look at the actual answers.

Comment: please, vote up my solution and my question... I have a low score, so I can't vote up other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it is the solution to my problem:
    package main

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "encoding/json"
)

type Client struct {
  Host     string `json:"host"`
  Key      string `json:"apikey"`
  Secret  string `json:"secret"`
  Username string `json:"username"`
  Password string `json:"password"`
}

type Config struct {
  Client Client `json:"Client"`
}

func main(){
  jsonmsg, err := ioutil.ReadFile("conf2.json")

  conf := new(Config)
  err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonmsg), &conf)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("Error:", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n%+v\n%+v\n%+v\n%+v\n", conf.Client.Host, conf.Client.Key, conf.Client.Secret, conf.Client.Username,conf.Client.Password)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Three things to fix:

- json.Unmarshal requires the struct fields to be capitalized to be exported or they are ignored
- You need the `json:"<name>"` specifier after the fields so the unmarshal knows the struct field to json mapping
- Your json was making multiple clients with one field filled in instead of one client with all the fields filled in

See example: https://play.golang.org/p/oY7SppWNDC

Comment: Thank you @Matt, it works but could you tell me how I can access a single information of the json? If I want to know the user of the first client, how can I access this item? This `conf.Client[0].host` does still not works.

Comment: @DarkSkull You need to capitalize "Host": e.g https://play.golang.org/p/dlhHAijeoX